# Code coverage with clang-cl compiler using llvm-cov generates report with tests files coverage missing

Tags: code-coverage, clang++, gcov

I am trying to get code coverage for a c/c++ llvm-clang project in visual studio IDE which is compiled as a static library and I have a test project written using Gtest to test the static library containing different source files, I can generate a coverage report using command **llvm-cov.exe report "my-exe" -instr-profile=*.profdata** but the report contains all the files except the files for which I have written the test cases. It simply ignores those files in the coverage.

I have used flags -fprofile-instr-generate, -fcoverage-mapping, and --coverage during the compilation of the static lib code. And it seems to generate .gcno and .gcda files as well. Why are the files for which the test cases written getting ignored?

Please note that the codes are compiled in Visual Studio IDE.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include a MRE see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example